# Enabling GD in PHP on linux for imagecreatefromstring function and sending email

Tags: php, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, xampp

I have Deployed my PHP web application on Amazon Cloud. I have installed PHP  and mySql there on server.
But my PHP installation is not supporting some features those were present in my default XAMPP installation on my development machine.
Features not working are
   imagecreatefromstring function
   and email sending functionality
because PHP installation on server does not have required files those are needed to include in  order to create image from string and sending email.

I have tried to manually install some rpm packages on server , but they conflict with existing packages.Also I don't have much knowledge of Linux .

What should I do should I create a new PHP installation on server and this time I think I should go with XAMPP for Linux installation , because XAMPP installation provides all basic functionality pre installed.

One More way  if possible could be placing some required.php files required for these two tasks in respective directories manually. Don't know whether this approach will work.

Please help if you have some similar experience or knowledge regarding this.
My scripts with these functionalities works fine on local windows development machine.

Comment: Now i have installed GD support and also enabled it , but then also imagecreatefromstring is not working on server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is the [PHP GD Installation Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)

You can also see if you have it installed by making a php file with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And looking for the GD section to see if "GD Support" is enabled.
[image]

Comment: I am not having any such GD support column  in my phpinfo file

Comment: Thanks man task completed successfully after installing gd package

Comment: I have same issue here, php was compiled --with gd but is not GD support column is shown into phpinfo() output. Also, getting uknown function using imagecreatefromstring. php-gd package is already installed. Stucked here.